# Momentum operator in position representation and viceversa

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, hilbert-space, operators, momentum

So I thought that

$$\hat{p}~=~-i\hbar \frac{\partial}{\partial x}~$$

and

$$\hat{x}~=~i\hbar \frac{\partial}{\partial p}~$$

but I have just encountered the next problem:

"Find the wave function for the fundamental state of

$$H = \frac{p^2}{2m}+\frac{1}{2}m\omega^2x^2$$

in the position base."

So they are asking me for: $\psi_0(x)= ⟨x|0⟩ $

I did as follows: I wanted to apply the condition:

$$a|0⟩ = 0$$

With $a$ being:

$$a=\sqrt{\frac{m\omega}{2\hbar}}(x+ip)$$

I figured that since

$$\hat{x}|x⟩=x|x⟩$$

and

$$\hat{p}|x⟩=-i\hbar \frac{\partial}{\partial x}|x⟩$$

I could just plug them in the equation for a and ended up with:

$$ \sqrt{\frac{m\omega}{2\hbar}} \bigg( x+\hbar \frac{\partial}{\partial x} \bigg) \psi_0 = 0$$

Which led me to:

$$\frac{d\psi_0}{\psi_0}=-\frac{x}{\hbar}dx$$

But checking the answers, they stated that:

$$\hat{p}|x⟩=\frac{-i\hbar}{\sqrt{m\omega\hbar}} \frac{\partial}{\partial x}|x⟩$$

And I don't understand where does the square root diving $-i\hbar$ is coming from.

Comment: What is the meaning of $⟨x|\hat{x}⟩=x$?

Comment: @Hector They mean that the position operator in the position basis is just x. $\hat x \psi=x\psi$

Comment: @AaronStevens No, "position operator in the position basis is just x" is written like this: $\hat x |x ⟩ = x | x ⟩$.

Comment: @Hector I was just telling you what I thought the OP meant.

Comment: I guess you could technically multiply the momentum operator by some real constant as long as you divide your position operator by that same constant so that the relation $[\hat x,\hat p]=i\hbar$ still holds. I might be wrong though.

Comment: @AaronStevens, My bad, I thought you were the OP. I apologize to you.

Comment: @Hector Technically you would say $\langle x| \hat X |\psi \rangle = x\psi(x)$ for any general $|\psi \rangle$

Comment: @AaronStevens $⟨x|\hat X|ψ⟩=xψ(x)=x ⟨x|ψ⟩$ Factor the $|ψ⟩$ out: $⟨x|\hat X=x ⟨x|$. Then, use the fact that $\hat X$ is Hermitian. Your statement and mine are equivalent.

Comment: Agree with @Hector here: notation is absolutely in need of clarification.

Comment: @Hector Yes I see now. The issue is that they have put the operator inside of a ket. Which technically is not the worst thing if the notation is properly defined, but I would advise against it personally.

Comment: @Hector  Sorry for the notation. By $⟨x|\hat{x}⟩$ I meant the position operator in the position basis, and by $⟨x|\hat{p}⟩$ the momentum operator in the position basis. I now realize that I should use the notation you proposed instead

Comment: @Ernestako Ok, the next step is to check the units (just like in Phys101). Note that when $\hat p \sim \hbar \frac{\partial}{\partial x}$ acts on a wavefunction it yields a quantity whose units are the units of the the wavefunction times units of momentum (as expected). How can you add $x$ (units of position) and $\hbar \frac{\partial}{\partial x}$ (units of momentum) in you expression for $a$? After you fix that, you will be closer to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a problem between different notations.
First of all, indeed you have $ \widehat{x} \left |  \Psi \right > = x\left |  \Psi \right > $ and $ \widehat{p} \left |  \Psi \right > = -i\hbar\frac{\partial\left |  \Psi \right >}{\partial x} $. But the annihilation operator $\widehat{a}$ is equal to $\frac{\widehat{X}+i\widehat{P}}{\sqrt{2}}$ where $ \widehat{X}$ and $\widehat{P}$ are dimensionless operators.

And it happens that you have : $\widehat{X}=\sqrt{\frac{m\omega}{\hbar}}\widehat{x}$  and $\widehat{P} = \frac{\widehat{p}}{\sqrt{m\hbar \omega}}$ Hence the expression written in the answer where the $\widehat{p}$ should be interpreted as $\widehat{P}$ I guess.

And by the way if you use these expressions you will find that $\widehat{a}=\sqrt{\frac{m\omega}{2\hbar}}\left (\widehat{x}+\frac{i\widehat{p}}{m\omega} \right )$

Answer (score 1):

Your annihilation operator is wrong. It is,
$$ a= (\sqrt{\frac{m\omega}{2}}x + i\frac{p}{\sqrt{2m\omega}})$$
To find $\langle{x'}|0⟩$ you just have to solve this equation:
$$ \langle{x'}|a|0⟩=0$$
$$ \langle{x'}|(\sqrt{\frac{m\omega}{2}}x + i\frac{p}{\sqrt{2m\omega}})|0⟩=0$$
Since $p=-i\partial_{x'}$,
$$\sqrt{\frac{m\omega}{2}}x'\langle{x'}|0⟩+\frac{\partial_{x'}\langle{x'}|0⟩}{\sqrt{2m\omega}}=0$$
On solving this differential equation you will get $\psi_0(x')$. To calculate any $\psi_n(x')$ just apply the creation operator n times on $|0⟩$ and take the inner product $⟨x'|n⟩$.

Note: I have used $\hbar =1$.